# Check if folder is versioned in Subversion using SharpSvn

Tags: svn, sharpsvn

I am using SharpSvn library for accessing Subversion. I have the requirement of checking if a specific folder is part of the subversion repository.

After some googling, I found the below code -

```
SvnClient client = new SvnClient();
Collection<SvnStatusEventArgs> args2;
bool result1 = client.GetStatus(@"D:\SVNMapping\demo\trunk\NewFolder", new SvnStatusArgs(), out args2);
```

result1 is getting true but args2[0].Versioned value is returned as false. But, the above folder is versioned and I can confirm it based on the icon -

[image]

I am not sure what I am missing in this API usage or if the API itself is incorrect for my requirement.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Can anyone address my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to check if a directory is under version control, it will be easier to use `svn info`. In SharpSvn you could do this e.g. like this:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Checks whether the specified path is under version control or not.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Internally, the "svn info" command is used (no network access required).
    /// </remarks>
    /// <param name="path">The path to check.</param>
    /// <returns>True, if the path is under version control, else false.</returns>
    private bool CheckIfPathIsUnderVersionControl(string path)
    {
        using (SvnClient svnClient = new SvnClient())
        {
            // use ThrowOnError = false to avoid exception in case the path does
            // not point to a versioned item
            SvnInfoArgs svnInfoArgs = new SvnInfoArgs() { ThrowOnError = false };
            Collection<SvnInfoEventArgs> svnInfo;
            return svnClient.GetInfo(SvnTarget.FromString(path), svnInfoArgs, out svnInfo);
        }
    }
```

If you would like to know in which repository the item is versioned, then you could return this information from the `SvnInfoArgs`, too.

If you really want to use `svn status` then you should have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11130666/3809520) questions since it explains why the option `RetrieveAllEntries` must be set in the `SvnStatusArgs` options and [here](http://docs.sharpsvn.net/current/html/AllMembers_T_SharpSvn_SvnStatusArgs.htm).

Comment: Thanks royalTS for both the links. Both are working for me.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the `GetUriFromWorkingCopy()` method

```
if (client.GetUriFromWorkingCopy(path) != null)
{ //path under version control
}
else { //path not under version control }
```